# Save Java script variable to file

Tags: javascript, php, html, server

Is it possible to save the variable "result" to a file on a server like the php line would do?

php:

```
file_put_contents($file, $result);
```

script:

```
<script>
(function() {
    var jsonArr = [];
    var obj = {};
    var rowIx = 0;
    var jsonObj = {};
    var thNum = document.getElementsByTagName('th').length;
    var arrLength = document.getElementsByTagName('td').length;

    for(i = 0; i < arrLength; i++){
        if(i%thNum === 0){
            obj = {};
        }
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('th')[i%thNum].innerHTML;
        var content = document.getElementsByTagName('td')[i].innerHTML;
        obj[head] = content;
        if(i%thNum === 0){
            jsonObj[++rowIx] = obj
        }   
    }           

    var result = "<br>"+JSON.stringify({"Values": jsonObj});
    document.write(result);
})();
</script>
```

Comment: As far as I can tell unless you are running a script on node.js, it will not be possible. I mean, without server side JS forget it.

Comment: is it then possible to put it info a php variable or something like that?

Comment: Send the result value through ajax to a php service, and then store it in the server... that can be just one way of doing it.

Comment: and how can i do that ?! I am an iOS developer and have no idea about ajax

Comment: Code a script with php that makes the thing that you want with the data that will be received. In order to perform the ajax request read this: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/